# Can we use assert in if statement?

Tags: python, pytest, assert

I have a test which checks some condition using **assert**. Can I use then assert in **if** statement? Like following:

```
assert 'string 1' in response, "Did not get 'string 1'!"
if assert:
    continue...
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: yes, got error 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'
thought i use it in wrong way

Comment: @bereal if assertion is true continue test with rest functions

Comment: @Roman if assertion is true, it will continue anyway, that's what assertion is for.

Comment: @Sayse I'm not sure if I understood the question

Comment: No, because `assert` introduces a statement, not an expression.

Comment: @bereal and if false, the script will stop?

Comment: @Roman if it's false, it raises `AssertionError`, and it depends on how it's handled. By default, pytests proceeds to the next test and will later report the current one as failing. With `-x` flag, it will stop immediately.

Comment: what if in my case the execution of the second test depends on the result of the execution of the first one? I mean the second test can start only if in the first assertion is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert` introduces a statement, not an expression, so it cannot be used syntactically as the condition of an `if` statement. There is no need to do so, though, because the statement

```
assert cond, msg
```

is equivalent to

```
if not cond:
    raise AssertionError(msg)
```